# Método delete do Model não apaga o registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o código abaixo na rota, mas não funciona! O que estou fazendo de errado? Ele está retornando os usuários corretamente, mas não deleta.

```
$Usuario = User::find(2);
$Usuario->delete();
return User::orderBy('username', 'asc')->take(4)->get();
```

Comment: tenta usar um try ali no delete para ver, porque é assim.
Uma alternativa é tu usar User::destroy($id)

Comment: Não funcionou o User::destroy($id), oque será que está errado? Não retorna nenhum erro.

Comment: dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
depois do $Usuario->delete();
ai tu vai ver o SQL, cola aqui

Comment: `array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1' (length=44)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 2
      'time' => float 0.68
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'delete from `users` where `id` is null' (length=38)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'time' => float 0.33`

Comment: tu ta usando softdelete ?

Comment: Não estou utilizando o softdelete, mas já fiz o teste utilizando o mesmo e ocorreu o mesmo erro!

Comment: posta o código do teu model.

Comment: No momento está assim:
`<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

 public $timestamps = false;

 /**
  * The database table used by the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 //protected $table = 'users';

 /**
  * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
  *
  * @var array
  */
 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
`

Comment: Está funcionando o CreateReadUpdate menos o delete que não.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize builder ao vez de ORM como teste

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', 2)->delete();
```

Creio que assim dará certo

Answer (score 0):

Adicione em seu model a definição da chave primaria:

protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

Pra mim funcionou...